# JSON Parsing Into TextView Android API

Tags: java, android, json, api, symfony

This is my API json

```
[
{
"titre": "Le Parachutage",
"auteur": "Norbert Zongo",
"categorie": "Litterature",
"editeur": "Harmattan",
"prix": "400 UM"
}
]
```

I created this Layout and i wanted to replace the "Textview" by theses datas ("Le Parachutage" etc..) when the activity is launched .

[image: Layout]

Btw This activity is launched by a preview activity via a button and an Intent .

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.kane.bibliokane;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import static android.R.attr.data;


public class ListesLivres extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView Titre, Auteur, Categorie , Editeur , Prix;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listeslivres);

    Titre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    Auteur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    Categorie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
    Editeur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    Prix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    new getData().execute();
}

class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.13:8000/api/liste.json");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }


        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String t = jsonObject.getString("Titre");
            String a = jsonObject.getString("Auteur");
            String c = jsonObject.getString("Categorie");
            String e = jsonObject.getString("Editeur");
            String p = jsonObject.getString("Prix");
            Titre.setText(t);
            Auteur.setText(a);
            Categorie.setText(c);
            Editeur.setText(e);
            Prix.setText(p);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
    }
```

I used all the Permissions i needed (Network , Internet etc..) in the AndroidManifest file .

Im using Symfony 3 , and i activated the internal server at 0.0.0.0:8000 so any device could use the API .

But the problem is that when i launch the activity , nothing is happening .
I still have the same layout , and TextView did not change .

How to fix this please ?

Thanks , and Sorry for my bad English , it isn't my mother's Language.

**EDIT**

After trying to debug and launch the app via the emulator .

Here's what i got :

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Titre
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
W/System.err:     at    com.example.kane.bibliokane.ListesLivres$getData.onPostExecute(ListesLivres.java:75)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kane.bibliokane.ListesLivres$getData.onPostExecute(ListesLivres.java:39)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you check what the values of t a c e and p are using debugging or a logging statement?

Comment: Ok , how can i do that ?

Comment: Please read this on how to start debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html. But before you do, have you tried to see if the JSON URL works on the Android device (using a web browser) where you are testing the Android app on?

Comment: Ok so i debbuged my App and Launched via The A.S Emulator . at the adresse 10.0.2.2 . And it says that "Titre" as no value . I will Edit my post so you can see the complete error log .

Comment: you didnt post the error :) BTW, I found it for you. Posting now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the error I've found in the logs:

```
I/System.out: JSON: [{"titre":"Le Parachutage","auteur":"Norbert Zongo","categorie":"Litterature","editeur":"Harmattan","prix":"400 UM"}]

              [ 01-02 21:52:56.868  5158: 5176 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x79a60fcff600, tid 5176
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 5176: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x79a605fe2ec0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Titre
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
W/System.err:     at xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.jsonparsing_stackoverflow.MainActivity$getData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:78)
```

So you see, your keys in the Json object are not capitalized. You want `String t = jsonObject.getString("titre");` instead of "Titre", etc.

To be fair, it could really be a few things.

I ended up rewriting your code until I realized my firewall was blocking. So turn that off if it is an issue.

The code I used after all modification was:

```
package xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.jsonparsing_stackoverflow;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Titre, Auteur, Categorie , Editeur , Prix;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Titre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titreTextView);
        Auteur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.auteurTextView);
        Categorie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categorieTextView);
        Editeur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editeurTextView);
        Prix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prixTextView);
        new getData().execute();
    }

    class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String LOCALHOST = "192.168.1.9";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://"+LOCALHOST+":8000/api/liste.json");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                char[] buffer = new char[1024];

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();

                String jsonString = result.toString();

                System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String t = jsonObject.getString("Titre");
                String a = jsonObject.getString("Auteur");
                String c = jsonObject.getString("Categorie");
                String e = jsonObject.getString("Editeur");
                String p = jsonObject.getString("Prix");
                Titre.setText(t);
                Auteur.setText(a);
                Categorie.setText(c);
                Editeur.setText(e);
                Prix.setText(p);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It could also be the manifest. Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in there.

There's also a chance it is your REST server.

Here's a rest server that does work (in node):

### index.js

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

var router = express.Router();  

router.get('/liste.json', function (req, res) {
  res.json([
    {
      "titre": "Le Parachutage",
      "auteur": "Norbert Zongo",
      "categorie": "Litterature",
      "editeur": "Harmattan",
      "prix": "400 UM"
    }
  ])
})

app.use('/api', router)

app.listen(8000)
```

to use it, create an empty directory, install node and then in the server directory run `npm init` — just press enter through the fields. Then: `npm install --save express`. Finally you can run it with `node index.js`

Comment: Thanks sir ! i will test that . indeed my keys are not capitalized and your code seems to be way better than mine . I hope it will work . Otherwise my Api works when i test it with Postman , and i used the Internet permission in the Manifest .

Comment: You're seeing the `org.json.JSONException` exception right? So you don't have to rewrite anything except the `jsonObject.getString` calls :) You're golden.

Comment: THANKS MAN !!!!!! you saved my life ! The problem was juste the Uppercase Letter , i should just write "titre" and not "Titre" lol .God bless you , this was the last part of my project !!